# Selenium Web Driver, ExpectedConditions [deprecated] alternative

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

The selenium web driver seems to be indicating that OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions method is now deprecated, I would humbly ask for some assistance in rewriting the below statement, achieving the same outcome.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));  
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id(newNoteInputArea)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently replaced all our `Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeVisible(By.IDK(element))` to

`Wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.IDK(element)).IsVisible());`

Comment: Thanks Doug, I will check whether the `InvisibilityOfElementLocated` method is available using your suggestion.

Comment: You wont be able to use "InvisibilityOfElementLocated" as it is a method within ExpectedConditions, instead use selenium IWebElement.isVisible() and negate it. !IWebElement.isVisible()

Answer (score 0):

They have moved the `ExpectedConditions` to another package that won't be maintained (unless someone steps forward).

The easiest (and cleanest) solution is to simply create a class in your framework where you can copy any `ExpectedConditions` you want to use. Even better, you can add your own as well.

So start from the actual class code (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs) and rename the class to `MyConditions`, for example.

Usage would be:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));  
wait.Until(MyConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id(newNoteInputArea)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @FDM, this does make sense, I just wonder did the Selenium team not create something better / a new method that supersedes `ExpectedConditions` class?